# Find root node name using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Given the following:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> contents=open('file.xml').read()
>>> node=etree.fromstring(contents)
```

How would I get the root tag name of the node? For example, if the xml were:

```
<Orders>
 <Order>
  <Digital_Order>1021</Digital_Order>
 </Order>
</Orders>
```

It would return `"Orders"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should just be the simple `node.tag`

Answer (score 0):

`node` is your root node actually.

But you might be experiencing problems because of the invalid xml, the last orders should be `</Orders>`